# Python: how to iterate over 2 iterables sequentially (not zip)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Imagine I have 2 iterables of any types let say for example list and string:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = "abc"
```

Is there a python friendly concise way to iterate over a and b sequentially (not in parallel like with zip) without tricking (the idea here is that a and b can be anything we just know they are iterables)

So no such thing as:

```
for i in a + list(b):
```

Ideally I would have something:

```
for i in something(a, b):
    print(i)
```

that would be equivalent to doing

```
for i in a:
    print(i)
for i in b:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `itertools.chain`: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain

You would use it like this:

```py
import itertools
a = [1,2,3]
b = "abc"
for i in itertools.chain(a, b):
    print(i)
```

which produces

```
1
2
3
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 1):

The "something" you're looking for is [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

for i in chain(a, b):
    print(i)
```

---

```
1
2
3
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 0):

[itertools.chain()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) does the trick. You should keep this library in mind when you are looking for things like this.